# How can I use GROUP BY with AGGREGATED column values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm learning SQL so I'm not sure about my question. I'm running the following query :

```
SELECT count(key), FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", DATE(min(created_date))) as First_Month
FROM `xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx_xxxxx.xxxxxxxx` as table 
GROUP BY First_Month
ORDER BY First_Month
```

Big query returns me this error :

```
Error: Column First_Month contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [3:10]
```

Basically I have a table with a list of account and payment. What I want to do is counting the number of accounts at their first month. Which is I think what we called a cohort analysis... but again I'm not sure.

I feel like there is something more complex beyond my question but I'm not able to express...

Comment: based on field name - `created_date` - i would assume that this field represents date of account creation so it would be the same for all rows of the same account  - is this correct assumption? or this field actually represents date/time of payment?

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant this field represents date/time of payment.

Comment: got it - naming was confusing though - but i already derived this from the fact that you accepted answer that assumed this :o)

Comment: Yep. Thus I'm still trying to figure this out. I will probably open a new more detailed question.

Comment: will be happy to help. as usually :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery.  Presumably you intend something like this:

```
SELECT count(*), FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", DATE(min_created_date)) as First_Month
FROM (SELECT t.key, min(created_date) as min_created_date
      FROM `xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx_xxxxx.xxxxxxxx` t
      GROUP BY t.key
     ) t 
GROUP BY First_Month
ORDER BY First_Month
LIMIT 1000;
```

You have a lot of history if you are expecting more than 1000 months of history.